# Craft cannot finalise update - There was a problem updating your database

Tags: database, auto-updates, updates, manual-updates

I've got an issue that following a server rebuild, I was prompted to update Craft, which I did by moving a brand new craft/app folder into place - then setting relevant permissions. I then tried to browse to the management once again, to be greeted by the 'finish up' button and the fact that Craft had to make a couple of changes to the database to finish the update. This is where I am encountering an error message of:

*Craft was unable to install this update :(
The site has been restored to the state it was in before the attempted update.
There was a problem updating your database.*

My database credentials are correct, and I have had this issue on 2 servers now with different builds (different ubuntu version, php, apache & sql). Could anybody tell me if they have seen this before and how to diagnose this issue?

Ubuntu 16.04.1
PHP7.0
Mysql 5.7
Apache 2.4.18

Craft log of the incident:

```
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] Preparing to update craft.
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] Finished preparing to update craft.

******************************************************************************************************
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] Starting to backup database.
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] Starting to backup database.
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] Finished backing up database.

******************************************************************************************************
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] Starting to update the database.
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] Craft wants to update the database.
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] Running migrations...
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] Total 23 new migrations to be applied for Craft:
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m141030_000000_plugin_schema_versions
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m150724_000001_adjust_quality_settings
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m150827_000000_element_index_settings
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m150918_000001_add_colspan_to_widgets
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m151007_000000_clear_asset_caches
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m151109_000000_text_url_formats
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m151110_000000_move_logo
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m151117_000000_adjust_image_widthheight
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m151127_000000_clear_license_key_status
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m151127_000000_plugin_license_keys
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m151130_000000_update_pt_widget_feeds
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m160114_000000_asset_sources_public_url_default_true
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m160223_000000_sortorder_to_smallint
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m160229_000000_set_default_entry_statuses
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m160304_000000_client_permissions
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m160322_000000_asset_filesize
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m160503_000000_orphaned_fieldlayouts
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m160510_000000_tasksettings
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m160829_000000_pending_user_content_cleanup
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m160830_000000_asset_index_uri_increase
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m160919_000000_usergroup_handle_title_unique
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m161108_000000_new_version_format
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] m161109_000000_index_shuffle
2016/12/21 10:35:49 [info] [application] [Forced] Applying migration: m141030_000000_plugin_schema_versions
2016/12/21 10:35:50 [info] [application] [Forced] Applied migration: m141030_000000_plugin_schema_versions (time: 0.121s)
2016/12/21 10:35:50 [info] [application] [Forced] Applying migration: m150724_000001_adjust_quality_settings
2016/12/21 10:35:50 [info] [application] [Forced] Adjusting Asset transform quality settings
2016/12/21 10:35:50 [info] [application] [Forced] Done adjusting Asset transform quality settings
2016/12/21 10:35:50 [info] [application] [Forced] Applied migration: m150724_000001_adjust_quality_settings (time: 0.005s)
2016/12/21 10:35:50 [info] [application] [Forced] Applying migration: m150827_000000_element_index_settings
2016/12/21 10:35:50 [info] [application] [Forced] Creating the elementindexsettings table
2016/12/21 10:35:50 [error] [system.db.CDbCommand] CDbCommand::execute() failed: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'Ui28t_elementindexsett$
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `type` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
        `settings` text NULL,
        `dateCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
        `dateUpdated` datetime NOT NULL,
        `uid` CHAR(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci.
2016/12/21 10:35:50 [error] [application] CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'Ui28t_element$
2016/12/21 10:35:50 [error] [application] #0 /var/www/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php(1352): CDbCommand->execute()
#1 /var/www/craft/app/etc/db/DbCommand.php(507): CDbCommand->createTable('Ui28t_elementin...', Array, NULL)
#2 /var/www/craft/app/migrations/m150827_000000_element_index_settings.php(21): Craft\DbCommand->createTable('Ui28t_elementin...', Array, NULL, true)
#3 /var/www/craft/app/etc/db/BaseMigration.php(33): Craft\m150827_000000_element_index_settings->safeUp()
#4 /var/www/craft/app/services/MigrationsService.php(149): Craft\BaseMigration->up()
#5 /var/www/craft/app/services/MigrationsService.php(91): Craft\MigrationsService->migrateUp('m150827_000000_...', NULL)
#6 /var/www/craft/app/etc/updates/Updater.php(180): Craft\MigrationsService->runToTop(NULL)
#7 /var/www/craft/app/services/UpdatesService.php(724): Craft\Updater->updateDatabase()
#8 /var/www/craft/app/controllers/UpdateController.php(405): Craft\UpdatesService->updateDatabase('craft')
#9 /var/www/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): Craft\UpdateController->actionUpdateDatabase()
#10 /var/www/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#11 /var/www/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#12 /var/www/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#13 /var/www/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('updateDatabase')
#14 /var/www/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(931): CWebApplication->runController('update/updateDa...')
#15 /var/www/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(241): Craft\WebApp->_processUpdateLogic()
#16 /var/www/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#17 /var/www/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#18 /var/www/public_html/index.php(19): require_once('/var/www/craft/...')
#19 {main}
2016/12/21 10:35:50 [error] [application] Failed to apply migration: m150827_000000_element_index_settings (time: 0.001s)
2016/12/21 10:35:50 [error] [application] Migration failed for Craft. All later Craft migrations are canceled.

******************************************************************************************************
2016/12/21 10:35:50 [info] [application] [Forced] Rolling back any database changes.
```

Many thanks in advance guys! Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Not sure exactly, but there's an issue with Craft 2.x and MySQL 5.7 that _might_ be the reason you're seeing these errors. See [Brad's answer here](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/12106/1098) for a fix.

Comment: Cheers for the comment Mikkel, I've hit a couple of issues with 5.7 but these were resolved. Initially I looked at an older server build using MySQL 5.5 and hit the exact same issue, which makes me think its something within the configuration of craft.

Comment: Allrite, it was worth a shot. You might want to hit up support@craftcms.com for this one, or ask for help on the official Craft Slack :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the key part from the logs:

> 2016/12/21 10:35:50 [error] [system.db.CDbCommand] CDbCommand::execute() failed: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'Ui28t_elementindexsettings'

The `elementindexsettings` table was introduced in Craft 2.5.  The fact that is already exists during this update indicates that you've already got some 2.5 database schema changes already in place.

Most likely this occurred from a previous 2.5 update attempt that failed (for whatever reason) and the database wasn't restored from a pre-2.5 update attempt backup before another update was applied.

Restore the database from a pre-update attempt database backup and try the update again.  If it fails that time, you can look in the log files to get the initial error that occurred.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I had this same error when updating to 2.6.2956 today. I deleted my old app folder, replaced it with a fresh one, and still got the same error message.

Found the same error in my logfiles, so I looked at the tables and saw that my `craft_elementindexsettings` was empty, so I dropped it and tried the manual migration again, and it went through with no problem.