# Site loads funny

Tags: apache

Finally after almost three weeks of trial and error, I have reached the promised land. Now that I am here, I notice that my site loads funny. By that I mean the following:

When going to my sites IP address (test environment currently) I get a very generic looking page that states "Index of /" and below that is the craft and public directories.
[image]

I must add that the Dashboard loads fine: http://192.168.10.39/public/index.php/admin/dashboard
Just when going to the main IP as shown in the picture.
Anyone else encounter this issue?

Have craft installed on a LAMP server, and can provide details if needed.

Thank you and I look forward to hearing back from you all soon. :-)

Thoughts? Thank you for all assistance here!

Comment: See https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12084/getting-this-sql-error-group-by-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a problem with your `DocumentRoot` config option.

If you have access to your Apache VirtualHost configuration, you should append `/public` to your `DocumentRoot`.

If you're configuring the host via some kind of control panel (i.e. via your web host), look for an option like "Web Root," and add the same `/public` path.

So, if your current `DocumentRoot` was `/home/username/website.com`, you'd change it to `/home/username/website.com/public`.

Many hosts will have a `DocumentRoot` like `/var/www/website.com`—same deal! Just add `/public` so it looks like `/var/www/website.com/public`.

This is just about as good a start as we can get without knowing more about your setup.

Edit: *The page you're seeing is what's called an "index," and it's dynamically generated by Apache for folders that don't contain an appropriate script or static file (typically, `index.html` or `index.php`)—you'll notice that the `public` folder of your Craft installation has this file—and that's where all the magic begins!*

Comment: Thank you for this, unfortunately this didn't work for me, made things a bit worse, see edited details above.

Comment: At the risk of sounding defensive—the above _does_ seem to have fixed the original problem, which was a VirtualHost configuration problem. Now, you're dealing with an entirely unrelated MySQL problem, which is only come to light now that the front-end of your site is accessible. Note that you'll need to visit your site _without_ the `/public` folder in the URL, since that's now factored into the base URL of the host.

Comment: No worries, good sir! I am here to learn; and yes, I see now that you did provide the correct answer to solving my original post. My apologies for sounding ungrateful - sincerely. 

Regarding the /pubic in the URL that is handle with: https://craftcms.com/support/remove-index.php , correct? Or is there a different article that I should look at?

Thank you and my apologies once again.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out there are two different errors happening here. I will move questions to a new thread and have made your answer the official answer for the original question.