# Craft Internal Server Error

Tags: craft2, mysql

I am getting the following error:

```
Internal Server Error
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #34 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'pottings_website.sources1.sortOrder' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

I have no idea how to fix it.

Its Craft 2.6.2911
PHP 5.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting this SQL Error: GROUP BY incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12084/getting-this-sql-error-group-by-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the methods answered in this similar question:

[Getting this SQL Error: GROUP BY incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12084/getting-this-sql-error-group-by-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by)

To fix my issue all I did was edit this file:

```
nano /etc/my.cnf
```

with the following line:

```
sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES"
```

The website was back up and running instantly.